# Creating trainangule div shapes with css like an arrow

Tags: css, tailwind-css

how can I create shapes like these [rectangular with triangular side ][1] and [octagon shape][2] white tailwind css?

so far I managed to create a div :

```
  <div className={clsx('flex justify-center w-28 h-7 m-1 text-enter',
                    styles.TrainanguleDiv)}>
 
</div>
```

and on css class I have:

```
.TrainanguleDiv {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  background: #6666ff;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.TrainanguleDiv:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid #6666ff;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
  border-bottom: 13px solid white;
}
```

which is not [what I am looking for][3]

can you please help me out
cheers

Comment: `SVG` and/or `clip-path` will help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create both shapes. You can look around it.
Link: Here's [live demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/S6maA1uOxM)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this solution, I would be able to handle localization as well through the `div` inside the svg

Comment: I am so glad that I helped you!!